# Cant call function after creating element. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appendchild

So my target is to run a function when click on "li" but number of li depends from user choice...
Function work when i create exactly amount of li elements...

```js
$("li").click(function(){
var e = $(this).attr("id");
   alert(e);});
```

```css
li{
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
ul{
 display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="questlist">
  <li id='quest1'>1</li>
  <li id='quest2'>2</li>
  <li id='quest3'>3</li>
  <li id='quest4'>4</li>
  <li id='quest5'>5</li>
  <li id='quest6'>6</li>
  <li id='quest7'>7</li>
  <li id='quest8'>8</li>
  <li id='quest9'>9</li>
  <li id='quest10'>10</li>
   </ul>
```

But when i would like to create list from user choice i cant run function already try:

```
function countList(ListX){
    for(k=0;k<ListX; k++){
        ke = k+1;
        node = document.createElement("LI");
        node.setAttribute("id", "quest"+ke);
        textnode = document.createTextNode(ke);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("questlist").appendChild(node);
        }}
```

and

```
function countList(ListX){
  for(k=0;k<ListX; k++){
  ke = k+1;
  document.getElementById("questlist").innerHTML += "<li id='quest"+ke+"'>"+ke+"</li>";
        }}
```

```js
var ListX = 10;

function countList(ListX){
    for(k=0;k<ListX; k++){
        ke = k+1;
        node = document.createElement("LI");
        node.setAttribute("id", "quest"+ke);
        textnode = document.createTextNode(ke);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("questlist").appendChild(node);
        }}

countList(ListX);

$("li").click(function(){
var e = $(this).attr("id");
   alert(e);});
```

```css
li{
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
ul{
 display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="questlist"></ul>
```

Both of function create me "li" elements with expected id, or at least after i open a console and analyze each "li" element i can see expected id.
Need

Comment: damn.... problem is some where else....  because snippet work... hmm..

Comment: no it was that. jquery issue :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the on method instead of click handler on li element, like this

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var e = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(e);
});
```

Rest of your code is fine, just use above code instead of $("li").click..

Working [Demo here](https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp)

Comment: Working :D awesome... and now can you explain me? why it was working on snippet?? but not working on web serwer?? using li on click??

Comment: The reason why this works, is because it attaches an event listener to body then delegates it to it's child list items. http://api.jquery.com/on/ - Whereas $("li").click(...) doesn't work in your case is because most probably the javascript code is running before the elements are rendered in dom - thus no elements to attach an event listener to.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation says:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on()

What you need is to make sure the actual element exist at the time you attaching the event. So if your `li` tags doesn't exist at the time of attaching event, the `.click()` method will fail. You next choice is to bind the event on one of the parents (in your case it would be the `UL` tag, like so:

```
$("#questlist").on("click", "li", function() {
    var e = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(e);
})
```

Also from now on use `.on()` method, it attaches event handlers to a selected set of elements and it works perfectly for elements present on the page.